# how to maintain different sessions of a same page?

Tags: asp.net, session, web

I need to open my page in two different browser tabs and work on both of them simultaneously. I have maintained a session in my code which have all the data from the page. When I try to modify in one tab it gets reflected in second tab. **How can I achieve two different sessions for the same page?**

Comment: Can you give more information on what technology you are using, some code examples?

Comment: when you reload second page the session variable should update.

Comment: I am using ASP.Net and I am trying to open same instance of the page in different tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it the way you ask for. Each browser have their cookie to connect with the user.

What alternative you have. The point here is to connect the same user (no matter what browser use) to the same data.

1. You force the user to login (and there you have the same data base on user)
2. You use some variable on the url that must be the same on all browsers to have the same data. Eg, on first browser you have a url like `http://www.test.com?s=123` and ask to from the user to copy paste either that url either the code on the second browser to been able to connect each other.

On each case session is not do the work, and you need some other database to connect the two data pages.

Answer (score 0):

The tabs in a browser share the same set of cookies, which includes the session cookie - so the pages use the same session.

So you need to find some other way to distinguish those two tabs.

You could add a "tab" parameter to the url that you use on that page, with some tab-specific value. You need to maintain that value in the url when you redirect, you can't store it in Session or a cookie.
The processing must then be done in a tab-specific manner.

If it is just for testing, you could use "private tabs" - they don't leak their cookies into regular tabs. But you do not want to force regular users to use this.